# Do we need separate authentication grant to access different salesforce object?

Tags: soql, rest-api, profile, user, authentication

We have a soql query which we run against the api that works on User object

```
Select Id,Name from User;
```

we are trying to enhance the query to retrieve the profile.name and role.name using the same query

```
Select profile.name,role.name,Id,Name from User;
```

we are getting `invalid_grant: authentication failure` when we run the query was wondering do we need special access to access these objects ? if someone could please point us in the right direction it would be of great help

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your SOQL to fetch role name from user object. Use the following query:

```
  SELECT Profile.Name, UserRole.Name, Id, Name FROM User;
```

You are getting `invalid_grant: authentication failure` so you probably need to include your API security token with the password.